# How to create MVC folder structure in Flask similar to Codeigniter

Tags: python, flask

I'm a PHP (Codeigniter) developer who needs to work with Python for a new project. I have decided to use Flask on Google App Engine. However I'm confused on how to create the models and controllers like in Codeigniter.

Can someone guide me on how I can go about this?

P.S. I'm new to both Python and Flask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your project folder structure can look like this:

[image: file structure]

Or this:

```
project\
    run.py
    config.py
    app\
        __init__.py
        views.py
        models.py
        controllers.py
        templates\
            index.html
            about.html
            layout.html
        static\
            css\
                main.css
            js\
                main.js
```

If you need more information you can check out this [structure for big applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/) or [for virtual environments](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications).